# Approximating a probability using Poisson.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, approximation, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

A salesperson has found that the probability of a sale on a single contact is approximately $.03$. If the salesperson contacts $100$ prospects, what is the approximate probability of making at least one sale?

My attempt:

Using the Poisson approximation, 
$$λ ≈ np = 100(.03) = 3$$ $$P(Y ≥ 1) = 1 – P(Y = 0)$$ $$P(Y ≥ 1) = 1 – \frac{3^0}{0!e^3} = 0.9502$$

I seem to have a conflict with the answer key.

The answer key:

$$λ ≈ np = 100(.03) = 3$$ $$P(Y ≥ 1) = 1 – P(Y = 0)$$ $$P(Y ≥ 1) = 1 – 0.97^{100} = 0.9524$$

The answer key seems to be using the binomial probability distribution. I understand that a Poisson probability distribution may not be necessary here, but the answer also gives the value of $λ$, and the answer key ignores it for the rest of the calculation. Moreover, I found this question in the Poisson probability distribution chapter.

Comment: I believe the answer key uses binomial distribution. $Y$~$B(100,0.03)$

Comment: I do believe it as well. I'm just suspicious that the answer key would calculate the value of λ but then not use it at all to calculate the final answer.

Comment: A puzzle. Maybe the solver intended to compare the Poisson approximation result with the "exact" result.

Comment: R code `1 - dbinom(0, 100, .03)` returns ` 0.9524475` in agreement with the answer key, whereas `1 - dpois(0, 3)' returns `0.950213` as in your answer. I think it is reasonable to use Poisson approximation, especially if the problem is in the Poisson chapter, even though $n = 100$ is explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations where you have a large $n$ and small $p$, the Poisson distribution can be used to approximate the binomial distribution.  The larger $n$ and the smaller $p$, the better the approximation.  This due to the Law of Rare Events, also known as the Poisson Limit Theorem.

You have a relatively small $p$ and reasonable $n$ for your problem; as such, one would expect the Poisson distribution to provide an adequate approximation of the Binomial distribution, as evidenced by your results.